# I am having issues with adding 14 days to a java Calendar object, keeps giving me Feb 31, 2012

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following code? It adds the 14 days to the object just fine but when it adds 14 days to Feb 17th it should come up with March 2, 2012 this year, but instead I am getting Feb 31, 2012. I have tried adding 2 weeks, single days in a for loop and everything keeps coming back to the same date. I have spent two days searching google and reading as much as I can but no luck. Hoping someone here can see something I am missing.

```
while(calNextPaymentDate.before(calEnd))
{
   Dates.add(date);
   calNextPaymentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14);
   date = (GregorianCalendar) calNextPaymentDate.clone();
}
```

The `calNextPaymentDate` and `calEnd` are `GregorianCalendar` objects and I have done traces to make sure that the dates are being filled in fine. It is adding 14 days correctly to the dates, but as I said I should not be getting a Feb 31, 2012 data at all.

Comment: ...I think this might be another example of "Java's Calendar is broken, use JODA."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that *actually* you've set the month to 2, so you're looking at March instead of February.

Try printing out the date - I very much doubt that it will show Feb 31st.

Don't forget that `java.util.Calendar` chose to use 0-based months, so for February you want month 1.

Comment: Oh, `java.util.Calendar`.  How can anyone stand to use you?

Comment: Use the constants in the `Calendar` class instead of month numbers: `Calendar.JANUARY`, `Calendar.FEBRUARY` etc.

Comment: I thought this might be the case as well, but when I do:

Comment: @Jesper Sure, but who in their right mind ever thought it a good idea to make February month **1**? I think that problem caught more people than not.

Comment: Too bad Java didn't fix the mistake C made with `struct tm`.

Comment: @Voo Ofcourse, that was a big mistake in the design of the `Calendar` API.

Comment: Ok so I feel dumb, it was in fact the issue Jon pointed out, but not quiet in the area that I posted. Sadly I thought I was initialize the Calendar objects just fine, but the zero based Month thing bite me when I was creating the objects. The dates are coming from an SQLite database that has the date stored as a string. I was converting the string to integer values and using those to create my object, but you guessed it I was not subtracting one from the Month when creating it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use Time instead of Calendar.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html